# Can I check for multiple file extensions in one rsync filter rules file per line?

Tags: rsync, rules, file-filter

I have a working rsync script, which recursively traverses our directory structure and loads one `.publish` file per directory. Each file contains a list of files to be publish. Publish means to copy files from an internal, not fully open source git repository to a full open-source repository. The destination folder (called export) is then pushed to GitHub. This way was chosen, because either we have not all rights on the files to publish them, or some files need a rework before going public :).

A `.publish` file looks like this one:

```
# git files
.gitempty

# Documentation
README.md

# Package
sync.pkg.vhdl

# Clock-Domain-Crossing (CDC) circuits
sync_Bits.files
sync_Bits.vhdl
sync_Reset.files
sync_Reset.vhdl
sync_Strobe.files
sync_Strobe.vhdl
sync_Vector.files
sync_Vector.vhdl
sync_Command.files
sync_Command.vhdl

# Altera specific implementations
sync_Bits_Altera.vhdl
sync_Reset_Altera.vhdl

# Xilinx specific implementations
sync_Bits_Xilinx.vhdl
sync_Reset_Xilinx.vhdl
```

I'm looking for a possibility to merge the `*.vhdl` and `*.files` lines into one line, by using something like: `sync_Command\.(vhdl|files)` (regexp syntax).

I searched the [rsync man page](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html), but I just found the `*` wildcard, which seems to be a bit to general.

**Is there a possibility to specify multiple file extensions per line?**

This is my rsync command line:

```
rsyncOptions=( \
    --archive \
    --itemize-changes \
    --human-readable \
    --verbose \
    '--filter=:en+ .publish' \
    '--filter=- *' \
    '--filter=P .git' \
    '--filter=P .gitmodules' \
    '--filter=P lib/*' \
    --delete --delete-excluded --prune-empty-dirs \
    --stats)
rsync "${rsyncOptions[@]}" "$src/" "$dst/"
```

Comment: Usually with `rsync` you can write something like `rsync -rv --include '*/' --include '*.html'  --include '*.php'   --exclude '*' --prune-empty-dirs Source/ Target/ ` if you want to include all the `*.html` and `*.php` files and exclude the other ones (`--exclude '*'`) and the empty dir (prune) but scanning al the _sub_ directories `*/`. Did you tried `--include`  ?

Comment: The include rules are specified in the `.publish` files across the hierachy. Each file also specifies if a sub-directory should be rsynced, too. We want to have full control over the published files. So globally including all `*.vhdl` files is no option.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you just have to mark them as include options (you can have as many as you like) ie:

```
rsync -rvzPm --include="*/" --include="*.doc" --include="*.docx" --include="*.pdf" --exclude="*" <srcDir>/ <targetDir>
```

Comment: As explained in 2016 to @Hastur, the rules are specified in a `.publish` file. `--include` can't be used. So your answer seams to be wrong or you need to correct your answer so `.publish` files are used.